# Should I create an Index on my table?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I've a table with 7 columns, I've on primary on first column, another index (foreign key).

My app does:

```
SELECT `comment_vote`.`ip`, `comment_vote`.`comment_id`, COUNT(*) AS `nb` FROM `comment_vote` 
SELECT `comment_vote`.`type` FROM `comment_vote` WHERE (comment_id = 123) AND (ip = "127.0.0.1")
```

Is it worth to add an index on `ip` column? it is often used in my select query.

By the way is there anything I can do to quick up those queries? Sometimes it tooks a long time and lock the table preventing other queries to run.

Comment: The IP column should be of type int if not already.

Comment: @Magnus I should then convert it to long int before insert it in database, isn't it,

Comment: int intAddress = BitConverter.ToInt32(IPAddress.Parse(address).GetAddressBytes(), 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, do create an index on `ip` if you're using it in other queries.

This one uses `column id` and `ip`, so I'd create an index on the combination.  An index on `ip` alone won't help that query.

Comment: How could I add it on my 20,000,000 rows table, does it will shutdown the serveR?

Comment: It's unlikely to shut down the server, but performance may be severely affected for a while. On the other hand, once the index is there, performance should increase dramatically - though I would recommend you work out the right indexing strategy on a back-up database first, and only apply to live once you're confident you've got the performance gains you hoped for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching by ip quite often then yes you can create an index. However your insert/updates might take a bit longer due to this.  Not sure how your data is structured but if the data collection is by ip then may be you can consider partitioning it by ip.

Comment: In practical terms, the "insert/update may take longer with an index" almost never leads to a measurable increase. It's one of those things that's theoretically true, used to be measurably true 20 years ago, but is now almost never measurably true.

Comment: Are you saying its negligible? We can log the times before & after the index for insert/update operations. Won't it give us  measurable time difference?

Comment: In my experience, adding an index to a table doesn't have a measurable impact on the insert/update operations (with the exclusion of clustered indices on SQL Server). Of course, if you have an excessive number of indices, this may not be true.

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb: If a column appears in the WHERE clause, there should be an index for it. If a query is slow, there's a good chance an index could help, particularly one that contains all fields in the WHERE clause.

In MySQL, you can use the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) keyword to see an approximate query plan for your query, including indexes used. This should help you find out where your queries spend their time.

Answer (score -1):

YES! Almost always add an INDEX or two or three! (multi-column indexes?) to every column.

If it is in not a WHERE clause today, you can bet it will be tomorrow. 
Most data is WORM (written once read many times) so making the read most effective is where you will get the most value. And, as many have pointed out, the argument about having to maintain the index during a write is just plain silly.

Comment: This is bad advice for several reasons including increased storage requirements, dml overhead and optimizer confusion. You create exactly the indexes you need, no more, no less.